# send array via session in php

Tags: php, session

i have this array

```
$banners[0] ='a';  
$banners[1] ='s';  
$banners[2] ='d';  
$banners[3] ='f';
```

I shuffle this array with

```
 shuffle($banners);
```

and than I have new random list, which I can show with

```
echo $banners[0];  
echo $banners[1];  
echo $banners[2];  
echo $banners[3];
```

and this new random list I want to put in session and send to another page on my website
This doesn't work

```
session_start();  
$_SESSION['sesion'] = $banners;
```

another page:

```
$banners[0] ='a';  
$banners[1] ='s';  
$banners[2] ='d';  
$banners[3] ='f';   




$banners = $_SESSION['sesion'];  

echo $banners[0];  
echo $banners[1];  
echo $banners[2];  
echo $banners[3];
```

how I can send new shuffle banners to another page with session? thans

Comment: Can you confirm that `session_start();` is comes before anything is sent to the browser in both pages?

Comment: in the another page you are assigning the $banner array with a set of values and again you are assigning $_SESSION['sesion'] to $banner. What's the point? Totally confusing!

Answer (score 2):

You need session_start() at the top of every page.

Comment: I have session_start() on every page, but I don't know how I put new shuffle list in session

Comment: Then show us your actual code, because what you have doesn't show that, and doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 0):

You missed the statement to start the session in the 2nd page.

So you need `session_start();` to be executed before you can access a SESSION variable through `$_SESSION[]`